# std::thread C++ 11 fails to explain me why

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I am running this very simple program, on Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop, however if I comment out the line sleep_for, it hangs after printing cout from main. Can anyone explain why ? As far as I understand, main is a thread and t is another thread and in this case the mutex manages synchronization for shared cout object.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;
std::mutex mu;

void show()
{
 std::lock_guard<mutex> locker(mu);
 cout<<"this is from inside the thread"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
 std::thread t(show);
 std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
 std::lock_guard<mutex> locker(mu);
 cout<<"This is from inside the main"<<endl;
 t.join();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the reason for a common code quality requirement that any object whose destructor has side-effects be created at the beginning of a scope, unless there's a good reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

If you change to `main` function as follows, the code will work as expected:

```
int main()
{
    std::thread t(show);
    {
        std::lock_guard<mutex> locker(mu);
        cout << "This is from inside the main" << endl;
    } // automatically release lock
    t.join();
}
```

In your code, there is a unfortunate *race condition*. If the thread `t` gets the lock first, everything works fine. But if the main threads gets the lock first, it holds the lock until the end of the `main` function. That means, the thread `t` has no chance to get the lock, can't finish and the main thread will block on `t.join()`.

Answer (score 2):

That's just a classic deadlock: The main thread obtains the lock and then blocks on joining the other thread, but the other thread can only join if *it* manages to obtain the lock.